# which daemons are running?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, launchd

Runing snow leopard, I'd like to find a way to say:

"Right now, this is what's is running and this is who is running it"  I've enabled process accounting and auditing, which should tell me this, but I thought I'd ask here to see if there were other insights.

So, how can I quickly find out which daemons are running, besides using launchctl list?  Or is there a way to modify that somehow to get a list of the running daemons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies about the self answering, but the BSD/Mach semantics are below the launchd stuff.

From the security manual:

> Listing Active Daemons and Agents on the System

To see a list of the daemons managed by launchd, run the following command:

```
$ sudo launchctl list
```

> Agents are programs that run in the background on behalf of a user, to provide services to that user. To see a list of the agents managed by launchd for you (since you are the current user), run the following command:

```
$ launchctl list
```

I highly recommend reading this manual, btw.   Page 223 tells you how to disable the

**Remote Management** and **Screen Sharing** daemons/agents.

Running by default, no less.

From "Snow Leopard Security Config v 10.6 available on the apple.com site.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps aux
```

in console :D

OR

```
top
```

for a live view

Comment: Right... but here's the thing:  Those tools work, yes, but there is an almost dual nature to osX I'm finding.  My mental model is exactly that, find, top, etc. I work with linux mostly, and I'm familiar with BSD.  However launchd and the rest of the osX stuff especially DirectoryServices, is a bit odd to me, and recently it's been hammered home that even though macports makes me feel like it's linux, I am missing a great deal by sticking to familiar tools.  I greatly dislike all this stuff running, thus my initial question.

Comment: oh how i feel your pain moving from ubuntu to osx.. however im slowly enjoying the change :)

Comment: It's quite nice. I was debating moving back to linux a while ago, but realistically, that's just crazytalk ;) However, launchctl should do it all, it's supposed to be running everything.

Comment: Did i help with your question / convincing you to admire OSx a little??

Comment: You misunderstand me I think.  I loved it before, but now I am fascinated by it.  IMO best OS ever, far better that iOS.  I'm actually going stop ssh'ing into places and sshfs them down to me, so i can stay in it all the time ;)